# Request to use token, but token was unavailable to the client. - DiscordJS Error

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make a bot that sends a message every day at 5 am EST so I'm trying to create a Cron job. This is what I have but every time I run it, it sends a message straight away instead of the time I want it to send at. Here's my code. I have it at 5 am in the code but I change the time when I'm testing it out.

Thank you.

```
const e = require('express')
const client = new Discord.Client()

const config = require('./config.json')
const privateMessage = require('./private-message')

const cron = require('node-cron');
const express = require('express');

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('running');
})


cron.schedule('0 5 * * *', function() {
    console.log('cron is working');
}, {
    scheduled: true,
    timezone: "America/New_York"
});

    client.login(config.token).then(() => {
        
        console.log('sending');
        client.users
            .fetch('749097582227357839').then((user) => {
                user.send(`hello`,);
            })
    
        console.log("nope");
    
        client.destroy();
    
});


client.login(config.token)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two `client.login` functions for some reason, please remove the first one.

You dont seem to use cron in the correct way - the `cron.schedule` function is where you put the code to repeat, not below it.

That is why your bot is sending the message immediately - the code is simply doing what you are asking it to do right after it schedules a cron job.

If you have everything else correct, your bot will actually log `cron is working` to the console at 5am every morning with your current code - the below code should achieve what you need.

To sum up:

```js
//declare packages here

cron.schedule('0 5 * * *', function() {
   console.log('sending');
   client.users.fetch('749097582227357839').send('hello');
}, {
    scheduled: true,
    timezone: "America/New_York"
});

client.login(config.token); //only ever use one of these events, it causes issues if you use multiple
```

there is also no need to do `client.destroy` - it shouldn't make any difference

Comment: Thank you, I got my bot to work properly because of you and I appreciate it. I was wondering if I could ask you another question/ask you for some more help dealing with the Discord Bot?

Comment: ask another question and @ me in the comments and i'll be sure to help

Comment: Actually, I think I may have figured it out. Thank you, though. If I do need help again, may I @ you in the comments after asking the question?

Comment: go for it, glad to help :)